# Space on the right hand side of a unary math operator

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I know that `\mathop{...}` is used to give some space on the both sides of the binary operator. Could anyone tell what to use to give some space only on the right hand side of an unary math operator?

**Edit1:** for instance, i want to define a function `NOT b` such that `NOT true` returns false, and `NOT false` returns true. How could I space `NOT` and `b` under math mode?

Comment: I think `\mathbin` is used for binary operators.

Comment: Yes, `\mathbin` is used to identify binary operators in math mode: `a\mathbin| b`. `\mathrel` is used to identify relational operators in math mode: `a\mathrel\circ b`. The spacing is marginally different.

Comment: It seems that `\mathbin` does look better then `\mathop`... I have edited my post btw...

Comment: @SoftTimur: I've added an `Edit1` part of my own in response to your follow-up explanation of what you're after.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a variety of spacing techniques in math mode that you could consider. The following is taken verbatim from [Herbert Voss' Mathmode document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) on horizontal alignment. It showcases the different types of spacing available and compares them very well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    % Taken from http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode
    \begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Positive Space}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{Negative Space}\\\hline
        \verb|$ab$|   & $\boxed{a}\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a b$|  & $\boxed{a} \boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\ b$| & $\boxed{a}\ \boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\mbox{\textvisiblespace}b$| & $\boxed{a}\mbox{\textvisiblespace}\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\,b$|\index{,@\textbackslash ,} (\verb|$a\thinspace b$|)\index{thinspace@\textbackslash thinspace} & $\boxed{a}\,\boxed{b}$&
        \verb|$a\! b$|\index{negthinspace@\textbackslash negthinspace} & $\boxed{a}\!\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\: b$|\index{:@\textbackslash :} (\verb|$a\medspace b$|)\index{medspace@\textbackslash medspace}&
        $\boxed{a}\:\boxed{b}$&
        \verb|$a\negmedspace b$|\index{negmedspace@\textbackslash negmedspace} & $\boxed{a}\negmedspace\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\; b$|\index{;@\textbackslash ;} (\verb|$a\thickspace b$|\index{thickspace@\textbackslash thickspace}&
        $\boxed{a}\;\boxed{b}$&
        \verb|$a\negthickspace b$|\index{negthickspace@\textbackslash negthickspace}&
        $\boxed{a}\negthickspace\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\quad b$|\index{quad@\textbackslash quad} & $\boxed{a}\quad\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\qquad b$|\index{qquad@\textbackslash qquad} & $\boxed{a}\qquad\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\hspace{0.5cm}b$|\index{hspace@\textbackslash hspace}& $\boxed{a}\hspace{0.5cm}\boxed{b}$&
        \verb|$a\hspace{-0.5cm}b$| & $\boxed{a}\hspace{-0.5cm}\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$a\kern0.5cm b$|\index{kern@\textbackslash kern} & $\boxed{a}\kern0.5cm \boxed{b}$ & \verb|$a\kern-0.5cm b$| & $\boxed{a}\kern-0.5cm \boxed{b}$\\ \verb|$a\hphantom{xx}b$|\index{hphantom@\textbackslash hphantom} & $\boxed{a}\hphantom{xx}\boxed{b}$\\\verb|$axxb$| & $\boxed{a}xx\boxed{b}$
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Additional horizontal alignment]

Consequently, here's an example that defines the command `\NOT{<bool>}` that places `\sim` (the negation operator), followed by a `\,` (`\thinspace`), followed by `<bool>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\NOT}[1]{\ensuremath{{\sim}\,#1}}% NOT{<bool>}
$\NOT{a}$

$\NOT{\texttt{true}}=\texttt{false}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Defining a command \NOT with spacing]

For more on mathematical typesetting, actually, **much** more, consider reading the entire document. Specifically for spacing in math mode, read Section **11.1 Math typesetting**.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thanks for the full explanation.

Answer (score 10):

You don't specify just how much extra space you'd like to see between the operator and its associated variable/constant, so I'll assume that it's the amount of space that would be inserted if it were a binary rather than a unary operator. In the code below, the "fake binary" operator is obtained by inserting an empty group, `{}`, in front of the otherwise unary operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
unary: $+1$, $-x$

fake binary: ${}+1$, ${}-x$
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit1**:
OK, based on the Edit1 of the question, I now believe that what the OP is after is a method for creating a "math operator" called, say, "\NOT", which inserts a bit of space between the operator's text and its argument. To get such an operator, I suggest you load the `amsmath` package and issue the instruction

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\NOT}{\mathtt{NOT}}
```

in the preamble.

An MWE, which assumes that the words "true" and "false" should be rendered in small-caps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\NOT}{\mathtt{NOT}}

\begin{document}
$\NOT b, \quad \NOT\textsc{true}=\textsc{false}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package (`\usepackage{amsmath}` for TeX Live) then page 15 of the User's Guide indicates that extra spacing (from least to most) is `\thinspace`, `\medspace`, `\thickspace`, `\quad`, `\qquad`. Negative spacing is also covered as is using symbols (such as `\,`) to generate equivalent amounts of space.
So the answer to your question depends on how much space you'd like.