# Abbreviations in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, xspace

I am trying to adapt Martin Scharrer's solution from [Macros for common abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/macros-for-common-abbreviations) to be able to use them in math mode.  Yes I realize I am about to incur some criticism that I should just use `\text{}`, but I'd prefer the macros to do the thinking for me.

1. I have three different versions of the `\ie` macro below and not sure which one is the correct one to use.  The third one (`\ieC`, which is what I have been using) seems to yields slightly different spacing.

   [image]
2. I am not able to figure out how to adapt the `\etc` macro for math mode to properly handle the case where there is a subsequent period as in `\etc.`. Furthermore, it appears as if the addition of `\ifmmode` screws up the `\etc` macro such that it no longer works properly even in text mode if there is a trailing period.

   [image]

If there was a version of the `\xspace` macro that worked in math mode that would be great.

### References:

- [Macros for common abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/macros-for-common-abbreviations)
- [Canonical way to typeset spacing in abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/canonical-way-to-typeset-spacing-in-abbreviations)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand*{\ieA}{%
\ifmmode%
    \text{i.e.}\ %
\else%
    i.e.\@\xspace%
\fi%
}%

\newcommand*{\ieB}{%
\ifmmode%
    \text{i.e.~}%
\else%
    i.e.\@\xspace%
\fi%
}%

\newcommand*{\ieC}{%
\ifmmode%
    \text{i.e. }%
\else%
    i.e.\@\xspace%
\fi%
}%


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\etc}{%
    \ifmmode%
        \@ifnextchar{.}{\text{etc}}{\text{etc.}}%
    \else%
        \@ifnextchar{.}%
            {etc}%
            {etc.\@\xspace}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
    $\ieA x < 2$ \quad \verb|\text{i.e.}\ |\par\noindent
    $\ieB x < 2$ \quad \verb|\text{i.e.~}|\par \noindent
    $\ieC x < 2$ \quad \verb|\text{i.e. }|\par\noindent
    
    \medskip\noindent
    $a \ne 0, b \ne 0, \etc$\par\noindent
    $a \ne 0, b \ne 0, \etc.$\par\noindent

    \medskip\noindent
    $a \ne 0, b \ne 0, \text{\etc}$ \quad \verb|\text{\etc}|\par\noindent
    $a \ne 0, b \ne 0, \text{\etc.}$\quad \verb|\text{\etc.}|\par\noindent

    \bigskip
    \noindent
    Outside of math mode \verb|\etc| no longer works at the end of sentence
    
    \noindent
    You should eat more fruit, \ieA apples, bananas, \etc. Next sentence.
    
    \noindent
    You should eat more fruit, \ieA, apples, bananas, \etc but also tomatoes.
\end{document}
```

---

The above MWE was for testing purposes, so I agree that the abbreviations there are not necessary to be within the math environment in those cases. But for my actual use case is in display mode where it is clearer to put that text as part of the formula as opposed to on the next line. For example:

[image]

Comment: Why should "etc." and "i.e." go in math mode? Your last formula is actually *two* formulas followed by text.

Comment: I hope it's OK if I'm curious: does my solution for `\etc` work for you, or is there any way I could improve my answer?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Your solution works great. I had attempted to adapt it to also work for `\ie` an `\eg` (without the check for the `.` since these are not intended to be used at the end of sentence). Initially this appeared to not be working, so had intended to come back to find out why. Turns out I had an extra brace group that was causing problem, so your solution now works for me in all the cases I can think of.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third version `\ieC` produces larger spacing since you have `.`  in text mode, i.e., the period ends a sentence. Usually one would probably write `i.e.\ $x<2$`, which corresponds to your first version `\ieA`. But it's up to you what you choose. Maybe in display math you'll prefer the larger spacing.

---

As for your second question, your `\etc` doesn't work because it lacks `\expandafter`. You test the next character with `\@ifnextchar`, but have a look at your code: When in math mode, you test the `\else`, and else you test the `\fi`! I know, this is the point where programming TeX can drive you crazy. What you have to do: use `\expandafter` to get rid of `\else` and `\fi` so that the `\@ifnextchar` can actually see the *next* character.

Just as a side note: you should put some space between `a \ne 0,` and `b \ne 0`. Moreover, your code really contains a lot of `%`s that could be omitted. Here's my solution for `\etc`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textetc}{%
        \@ifnextchar{.}
            {etc}
            {etc.\@\xspace}%
}
\newcommand*{\mathetc}{%
        \@ifnextchar{.}
            {\text{etc}}
            {\text{etc.}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\etc}{%
    \ifmmode
        \expandafter\mathetc
    \else
        \expandafter\textetc
    \fi
}

\begin{document}\noindent
    $a \ne 0,\ b \ne 0,\ \etc$\par\noindent
    $a \ne 0,\ b \ne 0,\ \etc.$\par\noindent

    \medskip\noindent
    $a \ne 0,\ b \ne 0,\ \text{\etc}$ \quad \verb|\text{\etc}|\par\noindent
    $a \ne 0,\ b \ne 0,\ \text{\etc.}$ \quad \verb|\text{\etc.}|\par\noindent

    \bigskip
    \noindent
    Outside of math mode \verb|\etc| works now at the end of sentences!

    \noindent
    You should eat more fruit, i.e.\ apples, bananas, \etc. Next sentence.

    \noindent
    You should eat more fruit, i.e., apples, bananas, \etc but also tomatoes.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your premises are fallacious. A TeX input such as

```
$a\ne0, b\ne0, \etc$
```

is simply wrong. Those are *two* formulas followed by text:

```
$a\ne0$, $b\ne0$, \etc
```

(one should ask whether the abbreviation "etc." is really good, but it's another problem; I never use it).

To answer the problem at hand, I'd say that

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\etc}{%
  \mbox{etc}\@ifnextchar.{}{.\@\xspace}%
}
\makeatother
```

is what you're looking for. The space factor setting and the space possibly inserted by `\xspace` are ignored anyway in math mode. I assume that `\etc` will never appear in subscripts or superscripts, that would be too much. :)

Similarly, `i.e.,~$x<2$` would be the correct input. Or, without the comma, `i.e.~$x<2$`. Putting the "i.e." inside the formula is wrong: it's no math. And in this way you have *no* problem with spaces. The definition for "i.e." can be

```
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.,\xspace}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.\@\xspace}
```

depending on whether you want the comma or not.

Comment: Agreed! Putting this in two formulas is a lot better. However, it's interesting to note that `$a\ne0$, $b\ne0$` and `$a\ne0,\ b\ne0$` (which I proposed) produce different spacing. Personally, I prefer the larger spacing of the second variant. Since I _also_ prefer two separate formulas, I write `$a\ne0$,\, $b\ne0$`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt the first has the normal space after a comma, the second has the thin space after a punctuation atom and a "spacefactor immune" space. You probably are using `\frenchspacing`. But the first is right, the second isn't. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's from the thin space after the comma - that's why I used the thin space `\,` `:-)` I'm not sure why `\frenchspacing` would play a role here. As for right or wrong, I just think that the second version is more reader friendly, in particular if the formulas are more complicated like `Let $n\in\N$,\, $f\colon[a,b]\to\R$ and ...` (call it a manual `\mathsurround`).

Comment: @HendrikVogt With `\nonfrenchspacing` the space after a comma is slighly larger than the interword spaces in the line, since ``\sfcode`,=1250`` (with LaTeX default setting).

Comment: Oops? I get _exactly_ the same spacing when I test `\nonfrenchspacing a, b \par \frenchspacing a, b`!

Comment: Ah OK, now I see: no extra space is added after `,`, but the stretch and shrink is affected. The modified stretch and shrink is OK with me, but I want the extra space, too `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt For a space factor f in the range (1000..2000) the stretch component of the interword glue is multiplied by f/1000 (and the shrink component by 1000/f), so the effect is visible only if the line is stretched or shrinked with respect to its natural length. If the space factor is larger, then the "extra space" is added and the same operations are performed on the stretch and shrink components.

Comment: OK, and now I also understand what you meant by "spacefactor immune" above. No, I'm not using `\frenchspacing`, and I see now that then the version `$a\ne0, b\ne0$` is not good due to that "spacefactor immune" space. In `$a\ne0$,\, $b\ne0$` the spacefactor is used, so I'll happily stick to my whim ... (Sorry for the tangential discussion!)