# command to generate a breaking half space or break, but not full space

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I like to use thin spaces in some in-line text lists, .e.g. of year numbers. Example: 2001, 2002, 2005, 2022. To compress the space needed, instead of space, I have been using `\,` between these year numbers.

However, occasionally, I get problems with line breaks, because the years are glued together by the `\,`.

So, the question is which command allows breakable thin spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding some command after the comma, which is error prone, I suggest to define your own command for these series.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tbspace}{}{\hspace{0.16667em}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\series}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \clist_use:nnnn { #2 } { ~ and\nobreakspace } { , ~ } { ~ and\nobreakspace }
   }
   {
    \clist_use:nn { #2 } { ,\tbspace }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\series{2001, 2002, 2005, 2022}

\bigskip

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\series{2001, 2002, 2005, 2022}}

\bigskip

\series*{2001, 2002, 2005, 2022}

\end{document}
```

You see that with just the addition of `*` you can change the formatting, if need be. The zero width `\parbox` shows that line breaks are possible after the comma.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal space is normally breakable when you use `\hskip` primitive without preceding penalty. I set the same amount of `\tbspace` like in egreg's answer, but (of course) I used only TeX primitives.

```
\def\series #1{\def\seriesX{\def\seriesX{,\tbspace}}\seriesA #1, {}, }
\def\seriesA #1, {\ifx^#1^\else \seriesX#1\expandafter\seriesA\fi}
\def\tbspace{\hskip.16667em\relax}

\series{2001, 2002, 2005, 2022}
```

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, a LuaLaTeX-based solution. :-)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
\luaexec{ function series ( s )
            return ( s:gsub ( "[\%s]+" , "\\hspace{0.16666em}" ) )
          end }
\newcommand\series[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(series("#1"))}}

\begin{document}
2001, 2002,  2005,   2022

\series{2001, 2002,  2005,  2022} % replace space with breakable thinspace
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just for completeness (and maybe to make @wipet's day too...), here's a solution that makes the Lua function `series` work with both LaTeX and PlainTeX. I'm not posting an associated screenshot as the output is the same as what's shown above.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{ function series ( s )
              return ( s:gsub ( "[\csstring\%s]+" , "\string\\hskip0.16666em\string\\relax" ) )
            end }
\newcommand\series[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(series("#1"))}}

\begin{document}
2001, 2002,  2005,   2022

\series{2001, 2002,  2005,  2022} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you replace `\\hspace{0.16666em}` by `\string\\hskip0.16666em\string\\relax` and `\luaexec` by `\directlua`  then your Lua function becomes independent of LaTeX.

Comment: @wipet - Thanks. :-) The reason I use `\luaexec` instead of `\directlua` in the answer shown above is that `\luaexec` lets me easily "smuggle" a `%` symbol over to the Lua side. (I need the `%` symbol in the pattern-matching expression `[%s]+`, which produces a pattern match for one-or-more instances of `%s`, Lua's "magic" character for whitespace.) Of course, I *could* use `\directlua` *if* I first replaced `\%` with `\percentchar`, where the latter could be defined via, say, \begingroup\catcode`\%=12\relax\gdef\percentchar{%}\endgroup. I'll post an addendum...

Comment: OK, I forgot the `\%` problem because the `\%` is a expandable macro which expands to `%` in my macro package. I can use simply `\%` in `\directlua`. Plain TeX defines `\%` using `\chardef`, then we have to write `\csstring\%` instead `\%` in `\directlua`.

Comment: @wipet - Thanks for this pointer. I'll update the addendum accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Should "et al." have a thin or full, non-breaking vs. breaking space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272506/should-et-al-have-a-thin-or-full-non-breaking-vs-breaking-space) which got me to the code `et\hspace{.16667em}al.`.

I now have a new command
`\newcommand{\tbspace}{\hspace{.16667em}}`.

This allows me to work with e.g.
`\tbspace{2001},\tbspace{2002}`.

Comment: please note that your `\tbspace` doesn't take an argument. Correct would be `2000,\tbspace 2001,\tbspace 2002`. The extra braces don't really hurt though.