# Math Spacing in the presence of a trailing/non-trailing comma

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, punctuation

I thought I knew how to use a `\hphantom{}` but don't know of an easy way to handle this case due to the comma. I want to get the text aligned for the `X` row. I added the appropriate `\hphantom{{}+1}` *after* the comma on the `X` row and yet the spacing is not correct. If I add the `\hphantom{{}+1}` *before* the comma, as in the `Z` row the spacing is ok, but I want the comma on the left.

[image]

But surprisingly, if I add an *additional phantom* comma on the right hand side to *all three* rows, then things align properly:

[image]

### Questions:

- What is the appropriate `\hphantom` to use to adjust for the spacing issues caused by the comma?
- Why does adding an  *additional phantom* comma to *all three* rows fix things?

## Notes:

- Yes I could add an additional alignment point just before the `that is` text, but I want the entire text to be able to wrap properly if the text is longer than the width of the column.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r@{}X}
    $X$~ &represents $n = 4k, \hphantom{{}+1}$ that is \ldots,\\
    $Y$~ &represents $n = 4k+1,              $ that is \ldots,\\
    $Z$~ &represents $n = 4k \hphantom{{}+1},$ that is \ldots,\\
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
But adding an additional phantom comma fixes the alignment:
\smallskip

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r@{}X}
    $X$~ &represents $n = 4k,   \hphantom{{}+1,}$ that is \ldots,\\
    $Y$~ &represents $n = 4k+1, \hphantom{,}$ that is \ldots,\\
    $Z$~ &represents $n = 4k    \hphantom{{}+1}, \hphantom{,}$ that is \ldots,\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, hope this makes up for the _hard_ question I posted earlier as this one seems that it should have an easy answer.

Comment: The X comma sees the `\hphantom` as Ord and adds the spacing, the Z does not, compare `$Z$~ &represents $n = 4k \hphantom{{}+1}, {}$ that is \ldots,` with the X row. You can enclose the X comma in braces: `{,}`. For the second table: Every comma no has an following Ord to include its spacing.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Not sure I understand fully. And how to explain that adding an _additional_ phantom comma at the end of all three rows aligns things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the third line is unacceptable, the error is in considering the comma part of the formula, which it isn't.

Text punctuation belongs in the formula only in displayed math, otherwise it should be typed outside the formula markers.

Consider reading

```
$X$ represents $4k$, that is ...
```

as

> *Mumble* represents *mumble*, that is ...

In other words, change all math contents into a *mumble*. If the comma is inside, it would be included in the corresponding *mumble*, so it wouldn't have any effect on the reading (and the grammar).

In your example you want to have a space as wide as "+1", with proper spacing, because the *formula* is wider in one line than in the others. The comma is not under discussion, because it's present in all three instances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r@{ }X}
    $X$ & represents $n = 4k$,\hphantom{${}+1$} that is \ldots,\\
    $Y$ & represents $n = 4k+1$,                that is \ldots,
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Notice also how to avoid the awkward `$X$~` in the first column.

[image]

Comment: Totally agree with last line as being unacceptable, and also with punctuation needing to be outside of math mode - it never occurred to me to go back into math mode after the comma to fix the spacing issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill This is however not a fix if the line wraps in the `X` column, because the space inside the `\hphantom` is frozen, while the one in `4k+1` is not. In this case you have to freeze also the formulas with `${n=4k}$` and `${n=4k+1}$`

Comment: If you are arguing that it is conceptually an error to consider punctuation part of the formula in inline math, why should one still consider it part of the formula in displayed math? Isn't it a *formula* in either case? (I also have the habit of including punctuation in my displayed formulas, but I'm just trying to follow your logic.)

Comment: @justin Punctuation doesn't belong to the formula, but in displays there is no choice but to put it along with the equation

Answer (score 10):

First, let us agree that in all rows `n = 4k + 1` and `n = 4k \hphantom{{} + 1}` produces the same horizontal space.

LaTeX organizes every math symbol in categories (examples, see reference 2):

- **Ord**inary,
- **Op**erator,
- **Bin**ary,
- **Rel**ation,
- **Open**,
- **Close**,
- **Punct**uation, and
- **Inner**.

These can be forced by `\mathop`, `\mathord`, `\mathbin` and so on.

There are rules which horizontal space should be placed between two objects.

According to these rules a small space (`\,`/`\thinmuskip`) shall be placed between a symbol of category Punctuation and a symbol of category Ordinary and not between one of Ordinary and one of Punctuation (the order matters).

This rule makes the spacing in `$1,2, 3$` to look like “1, 2, 3” and not “1,2,3” (spaces in math-mode have no effect). This is also the reason why using a comma to separate integer and decimal in numbers needs to be written as `123{,}456`. (The comma “doesn’t see” the `4` anymore and is at the end of a group: No spacing.)

Now, how does that look in your example? (I assume that the `\hphantom` space is seen as an ordinary symbol (it has to be something).)

## First Table

### First row

> … `k, \hphantom`

#### Categories

> … **Ord Punct Ord**

#### Spacing

> … **Ord** none **Punct** thin **Ord**

### Second row

> … `1 ,`

There is no symbol after the `,`!

#### Categoires

> … **Ord Punct**

#### Spacing

> … **Ord** none **Punct**

This makes a deficit of one small space.

### Third row

> `k \hphantom ,`

There is no symbol after the `,`!

#### Categoires

> … **Ord Ord Punct**

#### Spacing

> … **Ord** none **Ord** none **Punct**

Again, we are missing one small space compared to the first row.

### Solution

I guess you want natural spacing after the comma when no math content follows (the space after math will be used anyway), so let’s make the comma in the first row unaware of its following content (solution to the question) *or* as [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99042/16595) has stated, your comma is actually a text-comma, though I find the the `, \hphantom{${}+1$} that` solution cumbersome, in this case it is semantically correct (solution to the problem).

Take a look at rows *Y'* and *Z'* where I added an ordinary atom `{}` that effects the `,` as in your original *X* row the `\hphantom` does.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}r<{$}@{ }l}
    X   & represents $n = 4k,   \hphantom{{}+1}$ that is \ldots,  \\
    X'  & represents $n = 4k{,} \hphantom{{}+1}$ that is \ldots,  \\
    X'' & represents $n = 4k $,\hphantom{${}+1$} that is \ldots,  \\
    Y   & represents $n = 4k+1,                 $ that is \ldots, \\
    Y'  & represents $n = 4k+1, {}              $ that is \ldots, \\
    Z   & represents $n = 4k \hphantom{{}+1},   $ that is \ldots, \\
    Z'  & represents $n = 4k \hphantom{{}+1}, {}$ that is \ldots, \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

## Second table

In the second table you added an phantom-ed `,` in every row, but every of these commas are not followed by any symbol. They introduce all the same spacing, *but* the new `\hphantom`s (row *Y* and *Z*) act as ordinary symbols and activate thin spacing after the commas that were a last symbol in the first table’s row.

## Reference

1. American Mathematical Society, [Mathematics
   into Type](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf): Section 3 “Mathematics in Print”, pp. 37.
2. [mas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6964/mas) in an answer to [When one should use spacing line \quad or \,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25810/16595): [Examples of category symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25816/16595)
3. LaTeX Companion, second edition. *(I only have the German edition: section 8.9 “Symbole in Formeln”, pp. 540ff. and Tabelle 8.7: Abstände zwischen Symbolen)*

> [image]

Comment: Most excellent explanation of the issue.