# Automatically reducing spacing before punctuation in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, pdftex, microtype, kerning

It often happens that after a variable in math mode, some punctuation in text mode follows (both display and inline). Depending on what the variable letter was, the spacing between letter and punctuation can look rather odd:

- `$A$,` looks like [image] - which is fine
- `$V$,` produces [image] - here, the distance between V and comma is far to big.

There are lots of other letters that are not very well-spaced, U, W and others which end "too italic".

Is there any way to automatically fix this spacing? So far, I was inserting negative kernings all over the way, e.g. `$V$\kern-1.5pt,` giving [image]. Of course, the kernings have to be adjusted for every letter (and font) manually once; perhaps there is some functionality in microtype (pdflatex only is fine) that allows for this?

Edit: For me, it is not possible to include the punctuation in the math (`$A,$`), since I do use different fonts for text and math (which might not be too conspicuous for the fullstop, but can be seen for larger punctuations, especially the double colon - which, if in math mode would need extra treatment anyway).

Completely subjective MWE (here, same font):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, microtype, lmodern}

\begin{document}
   Proper spacing: $A$, $E$, $Q$, $R$. \\
   Acceptable spacing: $B$, $C$, $D$, $G$, $O$, $S$, $Z$. \\
   Poor spacing: $F$, $H$, $I$, $J$, $K$, $M$, $N$, $P$, $T$, $U$, $V$, $W$, $X$, $Y$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've posted a [new, LuaLaTeX-based answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329386/5001) that automates making kerning adjustments.