# Distinguishing between comma in list of numbers and in text

Tags: math-mode, typography

I am writing the following mathematical definition:

```
... where for $i=1,\dotsc,n$, $Ag_i=(AS_i,\mathscr{K}_i)$, ...
```

which produces:

[image]

There are two kind of commas, one in `1, …, n` and the other after `n` which is in text. How is it possible to make the two kinds of commas distinguishable so then it does not appear as though there is a missing formula after `n`.

Comment: The best way is to add some text between the list of numbers and `$Ag_i=...$`, or inverting: `where $Ag_i=...$, for $i=1,\dots,n$`. Note that you don't need `\dotsc`, only `\dots` suffices because it's smart enough to see a comma follows and adjust itself.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Because of the structure of the sentence I cannot change the order of the two elements (since there are more conditions after Agi=(ASi,Ki)). Thanks for the tip on dotsc. I'll change it.

Comment: You could use `;` instead of `,` after `n`.

Comment: If I don't find any way of making the two types of commas more distinguishable and different, then I think using `;` would be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Math Spacing in the presence of a trailing/non-trailing comma](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99024)

Answer (score 1):

There are not many possibilities to distinguish these commas. As you can see, the math-mode and text-mode comma looks the same. You could redefine the font for the math-mode comma or set the single appearing text-mode comma locally in an other font, but that will look weird, I guess.

I am collecting the comments together with my own thoughts for other possibilities:

- invert the sentence to get text between the two mathematical expressions
- use some other text separator such as the semicolon
- use some other math separator such as slash or semicolon
- separate the first mathematical expression by brackets `where (for $i=1,\dots,n$) $Ag_i=(AS_i,\mathscr{K}_i)$, or other stuff is ...`
- add some space with `\quad` or `\qquad` behind the first mathematical expressions to get a bigger visual separation

All this points are not really beautiful and as you tagged with "typography", you should consider to do, what I would do.

Rewrite the whole sentence. It is not forbidden to split in several sentences and to guide the reader through your text. This could look like:

> In the following, I will present some formulae, including the counter
>   $i$ which is defined as $i=1,\dotsc,n$. The possible formulae are
>   $Ag_i=(AS_i,\mathscr{K}_i)$, ...