# How to left align an equation, with a brace as left delimiter?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, positioning

This is my code:

```
\begin{document}
$$
\sigma(s,i) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
    \tau_{si} & \mbox{si } \{s,i\} \in E \\
    \infty & \mbox{sinon.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
\end{document}
```

I have the equation in the center. How can I modify the code to have the equation to the left ?

Comment: Just this one equation or every displayed equation? If the latter, use `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` and please, don't use `$$...$$` but `\[...\]`.

Comment: evry displayed eqation

Comment: ... and please, don't use `\left\{` and `array` and `\right.` but `\begin{cases} your stuff \end{cases}`

Comment: @researcher, you might consider using other tags. Your code does not have much to do with {latex3}, but more with {equations}.

Comment: Did Werner's link help?

Comment: @TVerron Thanks for updating the question title; it's a more appropriate one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fleqn` option for `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sigma(s,i) = 
\begin{cases}
    \tau_{si},\quad &\text{si } \{s,i\} \in E \\
    \infty, & \text{sinon.}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\quad` command is optional (though recommended by some authors) and introduces some horizontal space between the expressions and the conditions.

Notice also the use of `\[...\]` instead of the `$$....$$` TeX syntax and of the `cases` environment and the `\text` command (also from `amsmath`).

Comment: I think that the `\quad` should not be there, right?

Comment: @jmc why not? It's a common recommendation to leave a `\quad` space between the expression and the condition in a definition by cases.

Comment: I do not know why one would do that. Please enlighten me...

Comment: The necessity of such a `\quad` makes me think that `cases` was not designed well. I do not yet have a reason to think that. My experience so far has not caused me to think that such a `\quad` is needed.

Comment: @jmc in the end, it's just a matter of taste. Leaving a `\quad` space might increase readability in some cases. In any case, I'll add a note about the `\quad` being optional.

Comment: @jmc Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25810/when-one-should-use-spacing-line-quad-or

Comment: @Papiro I was just trying to find that answer, but you were faster. Thanks!