# Style question: Good spacing in (display-)math

Tags: math-mode

I was quite disappointed to find no recommendation on spacing in math-mode in the [AMS guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), so I wanted to ask if there is some rule of thumb for spacing math like

```
\[ x_n \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty) \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f(x_n) \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty) \]
```

Are `\quad` and `\qquad` really the best choice?

Comment: Instead of `\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad` you should use the correct `\implies`. You don't like the spacing around `\implies`? Well, you can change the definition *later*. **EDIT:** I don't really understand what you ask, but I do use `\quad` and `\qquad` to space displayed mathematics.

Comment: I think your choice of spacing for this case is fine.  `\quad` and `\qquad` and produce standard amounts used in traditional typogarphy.  The TeXbook discusses such issues, which is probably why the ams doc's don't feel that they need to cover this again.

Comment: see the answer by gonzalo medina to question 25861; there is a link to the manual *math into type* by ellen swanson, former editorial head at the ams.  there is additional good advice in a comment to that answer.  `amsmath` is supposed to have these principles built in, but it does depend on an author using the appropriate commands.

Comment: Here are the links to the [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25810/) and the [manual](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf) referenced by Barbara.

Comment: This is really a style question not a technical one: that makes it off-topic.

Comment: @JosephWright Does it really matter - five months of zero activity later. Also, why is my question off-topic if [show-off polling](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off) isn't?

Comment: @arney Periodically we try to sweep over the unanswered questions to find those that can be handled one way or the other. In the case of the question you link to, I'm not keen on it myself but it got a certain 'traction'. I will of course re-open this one if you are unhappy.

Comment: @JosephWright I consider Barbara's comment an/the answer - but sadly cannot mark the question answered, as it was only a comment.