# Math spacing when using quantifiers

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I'm often writing equations with quantifiers like these:

```
\begin{equation*}
x_i \quad \forall i = 1, \dotsc, n  
\end{equation*}
```

I've read this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25861/45570), but I'm not sure if my case is an example for a situation where one uses EM quad.

So my first question is, would you put a `\quad` space at that position?

The second question is, would you separate the first part from the quantifier with a comma like:

```
\begin{equation*}
x_i \quad , \forall i = 1, \dotsc, n    
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid the `\forall`: `x_{i},\qquad i=1,2,\dots,n` I think that the quantifier is even mathematically wrong (at least in several cases I see). Note that you don't need `\dotsc`, because `\dots` is able to figure out what follows. `\dotsc` is needed only if you have an open ended enumeration, such as `i=1,2,\dotsc`

Comment: (1) I'd never leave a floating comma. (2) in most of what I edit I use a qquad for this leaving the single quad for "f quad and quad g qquad for all..."

Comment: Logically, `\forall` seems wrong. I don't know if mathematicians use it differently. Or don't remember well enough to be sure. But logically, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @cfr assuming `x_i` is a boolean valued predicate, then it makes sense although would more normally be written with the  quantifier first, `\forall i \in \{1,\dots\n\} . x_i`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was more the `=` combined with the `\forall` which didn't make sense. (Although, logically, I'm inclined to see the `i` in `x_i` as unbound.) `\forall i \in \{...` for `\text{for } i=1,\dots`. It's the combination which doesn't look wff-like to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put a space before the comma, Also I would not use `\forall` with an informal iterator displayed as dots.

Assuming `x_i` is some boolean valued expression indexed by `i` then either

```
\begin{equation*}
x_i \quad \text{for all $i=1,\dots,n$}
\end{equation*}
```

or more formally

```
\begin{equation*}
\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}\mathbin{.}x_i    
\end{equation*}
```