# Where does not TeX make correct spacing and formatting in math formulas automatically?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath

I am writing book with a lot of math formulas. I am interested to print them correctly according to typography rules, Knuth's recommendations or AMS-society's recommendations.

I saw in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25810/when-one-should-use-spacing-line-quad-or) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas) some interesting points and even [reference for this book](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf), which doesn't work for me for some reason.

From this point I started to think of rules where I should help TeX to make correct spacing, fonts, symbols, formatting and etc. in math formulas. I mean where I should manually help TeX. I don't want break cases, where TeX makes it automatically, for example, `\sin x` makes correct spacing, fonts without my `\, \; \! \quad`, etc.

for example, AMS-society recommends to print `\int f(x)\,dx` instead of `\int f(x)dx`.

Here is the question. Where can I get list of recommendations or can someone provide cool book or answer with format rules for formulas where LaTeX doesn't make all work? All resources in the Internet refer to that site, but I can't access it.

Sorry, if duplicate, off-topic or something else.

Currently, I've found these rules and make a small list according to SE and books (I hope I will update them for me as my book will be edited more):

[image]

Comment: if you can't access "Mathematics into type", it's probably because it's on an ftp server, and many browsers refuse to access ftp servers, considering them to be less "safe" than web servers.  we at the ams are working on transferring everything from our ftp server to the web server, but it's an enormous undertaking, and will take time.  you can send a request to tech-support (at) ams.org and we will send a copy by email.  here's a new manual that may be helpful:[AMS Style Guide](http://www.ams.org/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-print.pdf)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you! I've written a request to ams.org tech-support.

Comment: You could create macros that may automatize that and give a readable code `\ratio{x:y:z} = \ratio{3:4:5}`, `\map{f: A \to B}`, `\forall x \in A \suchthat f(x) = 12`, `\set{ x : 1 < x < 2 }` or `\set{ x \given 1 < x < 2}` or `\set{ x \suchthat 1 < x < 2}`, `\int f(x) \d x`.

Comment: @Manuel yes, I can, I will think about that, if that would be really useful... but no matter I am interested in as much cases as possible where LaTeX does not do everything automatically

Comment: "Mathematics into type" has been installed on the web server, and should now be accessible to anyone at http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf