# What is correct spacing after $\forall x: $ in math formulas?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, typography

I am writing math book and I am interested how I should print them correctly. I know that the main thing is sameness across the whole document, but I am really interested in ways which are recommended by respectable persons and societies, i.e. Knuth or AMS.

I've already asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392329/where-does-not-tex-make-correct-spacing-and-formatting-in-math-formulas-automati) to find the true.

Now I am editing my book. I come here with the question which spacing is correct between the following variants:

```
\begin{align}
&\exists m \in \bbR{:}\quad \forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
&\exists m \in \bbR \mathpunct{:} \forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
&\exists m \in \bbR : \forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
&\exists m \in \bbR\colon \forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
\end{align}
```

[image]

Personally, I love the first variant, but it seems not so comfortable, so I don't think it is used by typographers.

Comment: Your title question asks about the space after `$\forall x:$`, but in your examples you have `$\forall n \in \bbN$` and the same space (`$\quad$`) after each of them.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR let's discuss both cases!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR oh I mistunderstood your comment. No, I have different spaces with colon-symbol. I thought that you want to mention that I ask in title about "for all x : " while in question there is "for all x in R :"

Comment: As I remember, `\quad` was recommended before `\forall`, but I'm unable to find anything online to confirm that, and my reference books are still inaccessible, in boxes.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429787/222887) it is suggested that you use `~` in front of `\forall`.
If adapting this, however, the question transforms to what command to use for the colon.

```
\begin{align}
&\exists m \in \bbR{:}\quad ~\forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
&\exists m \in \bbR \mathpunct{:} ~\forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
&\exists m \in \bbR : ~\forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
&\exists m \in \bbR\colon ~\forall n \in \bbN\quad x_n \ge m.\\
\end{align}
```

[image: Outcomes when used with ~]