# How can I separate a number and a 'forall' sign in a math expression

Tags: math-mode, spacing

How could I ensure there is spacing between the number zero and my 'forall' sign in the following:

```
$$\alpha'(t) \not= 0 \forall t \in I$$ ?
```

Initially I tried to do

```
$\alpha'(t) \not = 0$ $\forall t \in I$,
```

which worked perfectly well, but now I wish to write the expression between double dollar signs for formatting purposes.

The problem is that 0 is almost too close to my 'forall' sign now.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Just put a `~` before `\forall`, `\[\alpha'(t) \ne 0~\forall t \in I\]`. And please use `\[` and `\]` instead of `$$`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/121799).

Comment: @marmot thanks for the suggestion, I'm using this for MSE.

Comment: @Kim : what do you mean with MSE?

Comment: Math stack exchange. We use MathJax. I may be mistaken, but \[, \] doesn't seem to work well over there

Comment: That makes this question off-topic ....